# MySQL Table Structure - Storing a limited set of numbers

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need to store a set of numbers in a MySQL database. I need some help to determine the best table structure to use.

There are 20 numbers that will be stored in each row, along with an ID. The numbers can range from 1 - 80 and there are no repeats in this series of numbers.

Initially I created a table structure with 21 columns, an ID and 20 columns that store each individual number.

```
Id     | Num1  | Num2  | Num3  | Num4  | Num5  |  etc..  |
----------------------------------------------------------
0001   |   1   |   4   |  15   |  22   |  39   |  43     |
0002   |   3   |   5   |  22   |  43   |  55   |  58     |
0003   |   1   |   3   |  5    |  6    |  15   |  26     |
```

I've also thought of a table with 81 columns, an ID and 80 boolean columns that would represent each individual number.

```
Id     |   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5   |  etc..  |
----------------------------------------------------------
0001   | True  | False | False | True  | True  | False   |
0002   | False | False | True  | False | True  | False   |
0003   | True  | False | True  | False | True  | True    |
```

Can anyone give some advice to the pros and cons of each table structure, and which would be easier to use when searching this table.
For example, we would need to search for every row that contains 1,2,5,66, and 79. 
Or every row that contains 16,33, and 4.

Any guidence would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization); a way to organize data that prevents duplication and anomalies (like changing one record inadvertently changing another record).

Higher-normal forms depend on the meaning of your data, which you have not told us, but to start you should avoid ordered or indeterminate columns (like Num1, Num2, ...) and split your columns into rows:

```
  ID  Num
0001    1
0001    4
0001   15
...
0002    3
0002    5
...
```

In general, any time you find yourself adding a bunch of columns that depend on their position you are making a mistake. SQL has many functions for aggregating, combining, sorting, and reporting on rows. Use the features of SQL to produce the results you want; don't try to make your database schema look like the final printed report.

In answer to your comment, a query that returns only IDs that have Nums 1, 4, and 15, and no other ID:

```
select ID from YourTable
where Num in (1, 4, 15)
group by ID
having Count(ID) = 3
```

If Nums can be duplicated you will want something like `having count(distinct ID)`. If you can have different counts of Nums to match you will have to create a temporary table of Nums to match and use `having count(ID) = (select Count(Num) from TemporaryTable)`.

Note that SQL Server already has a `master..spt_values` table of integers to use in such situations; I do not know if MySql has such a thing, but they are easy to generate if you need one.

Comment: I do understand the concept of normalization, but I am a bit confused on how the above table structure would work for select commands. For example, how would one select an ID that contains 1 and 4 and 15?

Comment: @user3780155, see my edit. If that is not what you want, please provide example queries and expected results.

Comment: As @Dour High Arch (+1) explains, relational database is row (not column) oriented. You will be able to more efficiently process your queries by employing a db structure that defines each number in a separate row, 80 in the case you defined, that is if I  have understood your need correctly. Think rows, not columns!

Comment: Thanks for both of your reply's.
@Doug High Arch - Actually that is the exact query I have been using and it does return the ID's that contain all the numbers.

The problem I am running into now is that I would like to get not only the ID's, but also the number that corresponds to each ID in the number set. 
I have been able to get the required results, but the query takes nearly 15 seconds with only around 6,000 rows.

'code'

Comment: Ug,,, hit add comment on accident. 

'code'
select ID, NUM from Table where ID IN (select ID from Table where number IN (3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 17, 18, 27, 32, 33, 34, 35, 38, 47, 53, 56, 69, 71, 73, 75)) group by ID having count(ID) = 20;

Any advice on how to optimize this query?
Thanks again!

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24435686/edit) to provide information; do not try to add code in comments. Also show your expected results; for example do you want to show all Nums of the selected ID or only matching Nums? To optimize queries you need administrator access and use the EXPLAIN command.